# Flattening a delimited composite column

Tags: r

I got a data frame in R where one of the fields is composite (delimited). Here's an example of what I got:

```
users=c(1,2,3)
items=c("23 77 49", "10 18 28", "20 31 84")
df = data.frame(users,items)
```

(I don't build it; this is just for illustrative purposes.)

```
  users    items
  1        23 77 49
  2        10 18 28
  3        20 31 84
```

I want to flatten the second column in order to have a list of (non-unique) user IDs and an individual item per row. So I want to end up with:

```
user   item
1        23
1        77
1        49
2        10
2        18
2        28
3        20
3        31
3        84
```

I tried:

```
data.frame(user = df$users, item = unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$items), " ")))
```

But I get "arguments imply differing number of rows". I understand why, but can't find a solution to give me the result I want. Any ideas?

Also, what is the most efficient way as I got more than 20 million rows of this?

Comment: Are there always going to be the same number of items in each "item" row?

Comment: @AnandaMahto No. Each row could have a different number of delimited items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items <- strsplit(df$items, " ")
data.frame(user = rep(df$users, sapply(items, length)), item = unlist(items))

##   user item                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 1    1   23                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 2    1   77                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 3    1   49                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 4    2   10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 5    2   18                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 6    2   28                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 7    3   20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 8    3   31                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
## 9    3   84
```

or

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(df)    
DT[, list(item = unlist(strsplit(items, " "))), by = users]

##    users item                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 1:     1   23                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 2:     1   77                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 3:     1   49                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 4:     2   10                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 5:     2   18                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 6:     2   28                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 7:     3   20                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 8:     3   31                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
## 9:     3   84
```

Comment: As a very straightforward and easily readable approach, I like the `data.table` option a lot +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
users=c(1,2,3)
items=c("23 77 49", "10 18 28", "20 31 84")
df = data.frame(users,items,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rbind_all(do(df %.% group_by(users), 
          .f = function(d) data.frame(d[,1,drop=FALSE], 
              items = unlist(strsplit(d[['items']],' ')), 
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
```

It would be really nice to have an `expand` function, i.e. the opposite of `summarise`

eg. if the following would work.

```
df %.% group_by(users) %.% expand(unlist(strsplit(items,' ')))
```

Comment: That's some nice performance. It seems like this reverses the "users" column in the output. Any idea why?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - it does do something strange to the ordering. Not quite reversing.I might report this.

Comment: @AnandaMahto -- It appears to be due the class of `users`. See https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/263

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to install my "SOfun" package or load my [`concat.split.DT` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058), AND if there are the same number of items in each "item" string (in your example, there are 3), then the following might be an option:

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

melt(concat.split.DT(indf, "items", " "), id.vars="users")
```

Here's an example.

#### Sample data: 3 rows, 3000 rows, and 3,000,000 rows

I've added an "id" column so you can compare the output across the two options.

```
## your sample data.frame
df <- data.frame(users=c(1,2,3),
                 items=c("23 77 49", "10 18 28", "20 31 84"))

## extended to 3000 rows
df1k <- df[rep(rownames(df), 1000), ]
df1k$id <- sequence(nrow(df1k))

## extended to 3 million rows
df1m <- df1M <- df[rep(rownames(df), 1000000), ]
df1m$id <- sequence(nrow(df1m))
```

#### Load the required packages

- "SOfun" (only on GitHub) for `concat.split.DT` which makes use of `fread` from "data.table" to split concatenated values.
- "reshape2" for `melt`
- "data.table" for its awesomeness, at least version 1.8.11

---

```
# library(devtools)
# install_github("SOfun", "mrdwab")
library(SOfun)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] ‘1.8.11’
```

Here are some functions to test the speed of Jake's answer and this one. Later I'll try to update with "dplyr" too.

```
fun1 <- function(indf) {
  DT <- melt(concat.split.DT(indf, "items", " "), 
             id.vars=c("id", "users"))
  setkeyv(DT, c("id", "users"))
  DT
}

fun2 <- function(indf) {
  DT <- data.table(indf)    
  DT[, list(item = unlist(strsplit(as.character(items), " "))), 
     by = list(id, users)]
}
```

***Testing on 3,000 rows***

```
microbenchmark(fun1(df1k), fun2(df1k))
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#  fun1(df1k)  17.64675  18.21658  18.79859  21.21943  71.7737   100
#  fun2(df1k) 152.97974 158.44148 163.12707 199.77297 345.7508   100
```

***Testing (just once) on 3,000,000 rows***

Time would be in seconds here....

```
system.time(fun1(df1m))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    7.71    0.94    8.69 
system.time(fun2(df1m))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  177.80    0.50  178.97
```

---

#### Update

@Jake makes a good point in the comments that adding an "id" made a very big difference in timings. I added it just so that the output of the two `data.table` approaches could be easily compared to see that the results were the same.

Removing the "id" column and removing reference to "id" in `fun1` and `fun2` gives us the following:

```
microbenchmark(fun1a(df1M), fun2a(df1M), fun3(df1M), times = 5)
# Unit: seconds
#         expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  fun1a(df1M)  2.307313  2.420845  2.630284  2.822011  3.074464     5
#  fun2a(df1M) 12.480502 12.491783 12.761392 13.069169 13.733686     5
#   fun3(df1M) 13.976329 14.281856 14.471252 15.041450 15.089593     5
```

Also benchmarked above is `fun3`, which is @mnel's "dplyr" approach.

```
fun3 <- function(indf) {
  rbind_all(do(indf %.% group_by(users), 
               .f = function(d) data.frame(
                 d[,1,drop=FALSE], 
                 items = unlist(strsplit(as.character(d[['items']]),' ')), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
}
```

Pretty nice performance all answers!

Comment: Adding in the `id` column seems to change things a lot

Comment: @JakeBurkhead, you're right. I had added it so the output could be more easily compared and verified to contain the same data. I've updated with a benchmark showing how things look once "id" is removed.

Comment: Thanks for updating the benchmark. Those are about the times I was seeing from running it without `id`.