# How to convert data frame in an appropiate form?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have date frame with two columns (size and number) which looks like in the following way:

```
                size                        number
                large                     13,14,15
                medium                       7,6,5
                small                        4,3,2
```

I would like to have the following sample output:

```
                size       number
                large          13
                large          14
                large          15
                medium          7
                medium          6
                medium          5
                small           4
                small           3
                small           2
```

I would be very grateful for any help.
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739512/flattening-a-delimited-composite-column/21741867#comment32914500_21741867

Comment: +1, marking as duplicate