# Opposite of 'summarise' in dplyr: turn one row into many

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there functionality in `dplyr`that does the opposite of `summarise`, i.e., turn one row into many rows?

Let us consider a data.frame that looks as follows:

```
> testdf <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2), b=c(1,2,1,2))
> testdf <- data.frame(a1=c(1,1,2,2), a2=c(1,2,1,2))
> testdf$a3 <- replicate(4, rnorm(3), simplify = F)
> testdf
  a1 a2                                a3
1  1  1 -0.6264538, 0.1836433, -0.8356286
2  1  2  1.5952808, 0.3295078, -0.8204684
3  2  1   0.4874291, 0.7383247, 0.5757814
4  2  2  -0.3053884, 1.5117812, 0.3898432
```

I now would like to turn this into a data.frame with 4*3=12 rows, where each value in each cell would be atomic. In other words, I would like to expand on the column a3. The result should look like this:

```
> resdf
   a1 a2         a3
1   1  1 -0.6264538
2   1  1  0.1836433
3   1  1 -0.8356286
4   1  2  1.5952808
5   1  2  0.3295078
6   1  2 -0.8204684
7   2  1  0.4874291
8   2  1  0.7383247
9   2  1  0.5757814
10  2  2 -0.3053884
11  2  2  1.5117812
12  2  2  0.3898432
```

Note that data.frames similar to the one shown above can arise in many situations, e.g. when working with a lot of data (for reasons of memory efficiency). Similar functionality was asked for in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739512/flattening-a-delimited-composite-column/21742105#21742105).

I know there are solutions that do not employ`dplyr`, but I am interested in using it since I'd like to do this for grouped (`group_by(a2)`) subsets of data.

Comment: Using `data.table`. `setDT(testdf)[, list(a3=unlist(a3)), .(a1, a2)]`  If you want efficiency for big dataset, `data.table` is one option

Comment: Take a look at tidyr package by the same author - specifically extract, and gather.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be currently impossible, but under **[active discussion by the developers](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154)** with a target version of 0.5.

Note `data.table` currently allows this (see @akrun's comment), and also allows you to have arbitrary sized group outputs with arbitrary sized group inputs, whereas it seems like the solution being discussed with `dplyr` would require all groups to be the same size.  Here is an example:

```
> data.table(a=1:3)[, paste(a, seq(a), sep=":"), by=a]
   a  V1
1: 1 1:1
2: 2 2:1
3: 2 2:2
4: 3 3:1
5: 3 3:2
6: 3 3:3
```

Additionally, based on @AlexBrown's comment, you could do:

```
unnest(testdf, a3)
```

for your specific example, but that does not seem to work with the `group_by` / `summarize` workflow for reasons described above (i.e. you can't create `testdf` directly with just `dplyr::group_by`, AFAIK).